# How to make this code simplier to run faster

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a 2800x4800 matrix. There is data only in the first column. I want to add data the rest of the columns as well. The values in a row should continue like this: n = (n-1) + 0.005. I wrote a code with a loop and it works, however, it takes too long. How can I write this without a loop?

```
for j=2:size(Time,2)
    Time(:,j) = Time(:,(j-1)) + (1/(Fs*1000));
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to get the same results as your sample code in just one line by writing

```
Time(:,2:end) = bsxfun(@plus,Time(:,1), (1/(Fs*1000)) .* (1:size(Time,2)-1));
```

If you have a newer version of Matlab (>= r2016b) you can use implicit expansion by Matlab and simply write

```
Time(:,2:end) = Time(:,1) + (1/(Fs*1000)) .* (1:size(Time,2)-1);
```

But at least on my computer I do not really see any performance improvement by using this vectorization instead of your loop. The JIT compilation has gotten quite a bit better over time, so it would be interesting to know which Matlab version you use.

Answer (score 2):

It could be likes the following by replacing the computation for rows of `1:2:size(Time,2)-1` with rows of `2:2:size(Time,2)` (indeed you can remove the `for` to speed up). Notice we assume that `Fs` is a constant here:

```
m = size(Time,2);
Time(:,2:m)= Time(:,1:(m-1))+(1/(Fs*1000));
```

Comment: Like that, it fills every column,from 3rd to the end, with the same value.

Comment: @fuji_doji your code is like that. my code works well and each row is the previous row plus the specified value.

Comment: Probably.. I can't see the result of my code because my computer is freezing while this code is running. :/ It looks like should working but i dont understand it.

Comment: Now I see the problem but not the solution :/ I have zeros in every column other than first column in the beginning. After running the code, the value is 1/(Fs*1000) in every column except the second. (n-1) is not replacing with previously calculated value but always zero.